# Range updates in segment trees of sorted arrays (merge sort trees)

Tags: data-structures, sorting, trees

I understand range updates in segment trees using lazy propagation where each node is an integer.

Merge Sort Tree (source GFG): https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20220722205737/MergeSortTutorial.png

But when it comes to merge sort trees (segment tree of sorted arrays as nodes), how does one perform range updates such as incrementing a range by a positive integer k?

How do we go about lazy propagation in situations where the merge operation is not something as simple as sum, max, min etc. but to merge two sorted lists?

Will it still result in a logarithmic time complexity?

Comment: What do you mean by "merge sort trees"?  Can you [edit] your question to give some more context?  What do you mean by "increment all elements in all arrays" or "maintain the sorted order of the root node"?  Please set up the problem carefully by describing the data structure and providing all necessary background to understand what you are referring to.

Comment: I think you're going to need to provide a more detailed explanation of what a merge sort tree is.  That image is not a substitute for a careful explanation.  What do you mean by "merge operation"?